# Django Logging with FileHandler not Working

Tags: python, django, logging, sentry

I am using the logging setup below with a django project (also using sentry/raven). The sentry/raven bit is working fine, but the file logging isn't. An empty logfile is created, but whenever I use `logging.info('foo')` nothing comes up in the log file (i.e. it remains empty). Any suggestions?

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django/breeding.log',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working the way you wanted? I'm having this exact problem.

Comment: lol actually nevermind, I just figured this out.

Comment: Anybody want to post the solution?

Comment: @Colleen post the solution please!

Comment: oh good god I'm so sorry. I posted that comment like a year and a half ago and have no idea what I figured out.

Comment: Oh batman! not again https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: For those who may be tempted to use the 'django.request' logger to log the WSGI debug prints, note that it won't work. The prints are directly sent to stderr, the logging system isn't used for those. You'll have to find an other way to get those nice "[02/Oct/2015 13:31:22] "GET /assign/?locationTagUID=15 HTTP/1.1" 400 36" messages displayed by the django server.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue. It turned out to be a permissions problem. When I ran the development server for the first time after configuring logging, it created the file `/var/log/django/request.log` owned by my local user (stretch) with mode 644.

When I started the "production" server (nginx/uwsgi), the service would run as the www-data user and was unable to open `/var/log/django/request.log` for writing. Simply deleting the log file and restarting uwsgi was enough to get it going, but I'll have to come up with a more elegant long-term fix.

Answer (score 2):

### This is a [Quick Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49974748/3702377).

---

### More complete:

In Django logging setting follow this script:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)3.3s %(asctime)22.22s [%(name)s:%(funcName)s] {%(process)d} %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry-warn': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'sentry-info': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'sentry-error': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['sentry-warn', 'console', 'file', 'sentry-info', 'sentry-error'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry-warn': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['sentry-warn', 'console', 'file'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry-error': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'sentry-error'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry-info': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'sentry-info'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'mail_admins'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'mail_admins'],
        'level': 'INFO'
    },
}
```

### Testing:

```
from logging import getLogger

logger = getLogger('sentry')
log_war = getLogger('sentry-warn')
log_inf = getLogger('sentry-info')
log_err = getLogger('sentry-error')

logger.warning('warn')
logger.info('info')
logger.error('error')

log_err.error('new error') 
log_war.warning('new warn')  
log_inf.info('new info')
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work you have to add the '*file*' handler to each logger, like this:

```
'loggers': {
    'django.db.backends': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'handlers': ['file','console'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'raven': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['file','console'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'sentry.errors': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['file','console'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
},
```

Otherwise, the loggers won't write anything to the specified file.