# Python Django app logger logs in different app directory

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a django project with 3 different apps (A, B, C).

In my `settings.py` file I am loading the apps in this order:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Rest framework
    'django_filters',
    'django_apscheduler',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    # Project applications
    'application_A.apps.ApplicationAConfig',
    'application_B.apps.ApplicationBConfig',
    'application_C.apps.ApplicationCConfig',
    ...
    ]`

I have a `logging.conf` separately file in each of A, B, C:

**log_config.conf**

```
[loggers]
keys=root,LogRunner

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=logfileformatter

[logger_root]
handlers=fileHandler, consoleHandler
level=INFO
qualname=root
propagate=0

[logger_LogRunner]
handlers=fileHandler
level=INFO
qualname=nas_app_master
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=logfileformatter
args=(sys.stdout,)
level=INFO

[handler_fileHandler]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
args=('%(logfilename)s','a',500000,100,'utf8')
formatter=logfileformatter

[formatter_logfileformatter]
format=%(levelname)-10s | %(asctime)s | %(name)-25s | %(filename)-20s:%(lineno)3s | %(funcName)15s() | %(message)s
```

I instantiate my logger in each of my separate apps using a `getLogger` method I wrote which takes in a class `__name__` as so (I have helper methods that get app and config directories properly):

```
    config_file = get_config_directory() + 'log_config.conf'
    _log_url = get_app_root() + '/logs/' + log_file_name + '.log'
    logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, defaults={'logfilename': _log_url}, disable_existing_loggers=False)
    logger = logging.getLogger(log_class)  # logger for this module
    return logger
```

Now all three apps have the same logging config and the same `getLogger`.

**My issue**
What is happening is that logs for Application A are sometimes getting stored in `\path\to\app_A\appA.log` but often times they are getting stored in `app_B\appA.log` as well.

*Why does this happen?*

*Should each application have it's own file handler?* One thing I noticed when I was debugging was that each of these loggers I instantiated in my app had no file handlers of their own - so they **defaulted to the root logger's file handlers**.

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49974872/3702377) help you ?

Comment: Thanks - I didn't see this post in my search! I will try this out and see